# Trouble adding two matrices using multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I seem to get input for the first matrix, but when I ask the user to enter input for second matrix, the program crashes..why is this? cant figure it out, I even tried allocating memory, outcome is the same...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOLUMNS 10 

// dealing with 2D arrays, passing to function etc
void read_input(int (*a)[MAXCOLUMNS], int n_rows, int n_columns);
void print_sum (int (*a)[MAXCOLUMNS], int (*b)[MAXCOLUMNS], int (*c)[MAXCOLUMNS], int    n_rows, int n_columns);

int main() {
    int i;
    int rows;
    int columns;

    int (*two_d_array)[MAXCOLUMNS];
    int (*two_d_array2)[MAXCOLUMNS];    
    int (*output)[MAXCOLUMNS];

    printf("enter the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    printf("enter the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    printf("enter data into array number 1\n");
    read_input(two_d_array, rows, columns);

    printf("enter data for 2d array number 2\n");
    read_input(two_d_array2, rows, columns);

    print_sum(two_d_array, two_d_array2, output, rows, columns);

    return 0;
}

void read_input(int (*a)[MAXCOLUMNS], int n_rows, int n_columns) {
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n_columns; ++j) {
            printf("enter details for rows number %d and column number %d\n", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", (*(a+i)+j));
            getchar();
        }
    }   
}

void print_sum (int (*a)[MAXCOLUMNS], int (*b)[MAXCOLUMNS], int (*c)[MAXCOLUMNS], int n_rows, int n_columns) {
    int i;
    int j;

    // computing sum
    for (i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n_columns; j++) {
            *(*(c+i)+j) = *(*(a+i)+j) + *(*(b+i)+j);
        }
    }

    // printing sum
    for (i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < n_columns; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", *(*(c+i)+j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "even tried allocating memory" — and stopped to do so exactly why? Do you think that whatever error you were having, and the error of not allocating memory where memory is needed, will somehow cancel out?

Comment: I didn't run your code but you should at least initialize your arrays, e.g., `int (*two_d_array)[MAXCOLUMNS] = NULL;`

Comment: @n.m i tried allocating memory like this

Comment: two_d_array[i] = (int*) malloc (columns * sizeof(int));
 two_d_array2[i] = (int*) malloc (columns * sizeof(int));
 output[i] = (int*) malloc (columns * sizeof(int)); @n.m

Comment: but it says incompatible types in assignment, where am i going wrong? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Edit your question of you want to add new information. Code in comments is unreadable. (BTW removing lines of code that the compiler complains about is not a very good error-correcting strategy).

Comment: `int two_d_array[rows][columns];` in C99.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY since i tried it and wasnt doing it correctly.

Comment: _where am i going wrong?_ Has not been properly to secure memory.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you type in a example of how to allocate memory for 2d array

Comment: I think it is a good start `int **` If you do not have to stick to `MAXCOLUMNS`.

Answer (score 0):

for C99

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOLUMNS 10 

void read_input(int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols]);
void print_sum (int rows, int cols, int in1[rows][cols], int in2[rows][cols], int out[rows][cols]);

int main(void) {
    int i, rows, columns;

    printf("enter the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    printf("enter the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
    //if(columns > MAXCOLUMNS){ fprintf(stderr, "too large!"); return 1); }
    int array1[rows][columns];
    int array2[rows][columns];
    int array3[rows][columns];

    printf("enter data into array number 1\n");
    read_input(rows, columns, array1);

    printf("enter data for 2d array number 2\n");
    read_input(rows, columns, array2);

    print_sum(rows, columns, array1, array2, array3);

    return 0;
}

void read_input(int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols]){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            printf("enter details for rows number %d and column number %d\n", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }   
}

void print_sum (int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols], int b[rows][cols], int c[rows][cols]){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        printf("\n");,,
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            c[i][j] = a[i][j]  + b[i][j];
            printf("%d\t", c[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

for int ** (2D_ARRAY)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 5;
    int **array;
    int r, c;
    //allocate
    array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        array[r] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }
    //set
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            array[r][c] = r * 10 + c;
        }
    }
    //print
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            printf("%02d ", array[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

for int (**)[SIZE]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

int main(void){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 5;
    int (**array)[MAX];
    int r, c;
    //allocate
    array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int (*)[MAX]));
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        array[r] = malloc(sizeof(int[MAX]));
    }
    //set
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            (*array[r])[c] = r * 10 + c;
        }
    }
    //print
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            printf("%02d ", (*array[r])[c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

for int (*)[SIZE]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

int main(void){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 5;
    int (*array)[MAX];
    int r, c;
    //allocate
    array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int[MAX]));
    //set
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            array[r][c] = r * 10 + c;
        }
    }
    //print
    for(r = 0; r < rows ; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            printf("%02d ", array[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: when is **array[MAX] used? is it another way of writing (*array)[MAXSIZE] or is it array of pointers like *array[MAXSIZE] ? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: and how do i know when to write malloc like this "array[i] =int*malloc(columns * sizeof(int)); where i is incremented in for loop to the max number of rows, and columns represents max no. of columns, why didnt u multiply columns with sizeof int in the **array example? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: array = malloc (rows *sizeof(int(*)[MAXSIZE]));
 
 for ( i = 0; i <rows ;i ++)
 array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int[MAXSIZE])); //i tried to allocate memory like this the way u said but it says incompatible types in assignment..

Comment: @user3151918 _why didnt u multiply columns with sizeof int in the **array example?_ `array[r] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));` i did multiply column.

Comment: @user3151918 _array = malloc (rows sizeof(int()[MAXSIZE])); for ( i = 0; i <rows ;i ++) array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int[MAXSIZE]));_  It seems wrong in various ways.

Comment: @user3151918 **array[MAX] , (*array)[MAXSIZE] , *array[MAXSIZE] , It  different